# Need help converting PRISM Unity Module Init to PRISM MEF Module Init

Tags: prism, unity-container, mef, devforce

I need help converting the following class for use in a program that I am developing. The original was a demo program from `IdeaBlade` called `"PRISM EXPLORER"` based on `Unity`. I need help converting one part from UNITY to MEF. I handled everything else. Just stuck on this one. I already marked my classes with the MEF "[EXPORT(typeof(XXX))]" and I think I need to use the "ComposeExportedValue" somehow. The confusing part is finding the equivelant for this line:

```
var provider = 
    (IEntityManagerProvider) _container.Resolve<IPersistenceGateway>();
  _container.RegisterInstance<IEntityManagerProvider>(provider);
```

THANKS!

The following is the entire class I need to convert. You can find the original here: [Ideablade PRISM Page](http://www.ideablade.com/solutions/prism.aspx)

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Regions;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using PrismExplorer.Infrastructure;
namespace ModelExplorer.Explorer {
  public class ExplorerModule : IModule {

    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public ExplorerModule(IUnityContainer container) {
      _container = container;
    }

    public void Initialize() {
      InitializeContainer();
      SetViews();
    }

    // ToDo: Consider getting from configuration
    private void InitializeContainer() {
      RegisterGatewayAndEntityManagerProvider();

      _container.RegisterType<IQueryRepository, QueryRepository>(
        new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()); // singleton
    }

    private void RegisterGatewayAndEntityManagerProvider() {
      _container.RegisterType<IPersistenceGateway, PrismExplorerPersistenceGateway>(
        new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()); // singleton

      var provider = 
        (IEntityManagerProvider) _container.Resolve<IPersistenceGateway>();
      _container.RegisterInstance<IEntityManagerProvider>(provider);
    }

    private void SetViews() {
      var regionManager = _container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();

      var view = _container.Resolve<ExplorerView>();
      regionManager.AddToRegion(RegionNames.MainRegion, view);

      regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainRegion, typeof(ExplorerView));
    }


    // Destructor strictly to demonstrate when module is GC'd
    //~MevModule() {
    //  System.Console.WriteLine("Goodbye, MevModule");
    //}

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two corresponding methods on a `CompositionContainer` are `ComposeExportedValue<T>(...)`, which allows you to add a specific instance to the container, and `GetExportedValue<T>(...)` which gets an instance of `T` from the container.

If you can design your types in a way to reduce this use of *service location* and try and prefer constructor injection, it will make your code much easier to maintain and test. E.g., could your code be transformed into:

```
[Export(typeof(IModule))]
public class ExplorerModule : IModule
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ExplorerModule(IPersistenceGateway gateway)
    {

    }
}
```